# Why does my electric meter not read anything?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I have a ZMG405CR4.060b.37 Landis+Gyr electric meter. This meter uses the IEC62053-22 communication protocol. In the device it also says "Landis+Gyr E550", I don't know what that is but could be useful.
I'm trying to produce a Python program using PySerial to replicate the conversation the device has when I use MAP110 (An official program to read every type of data from a Landis device)
The device is connected via an optical reader cable connected to a serial to USB adapter, to connect it to an USB port of the PC.
I've been monitoring the port communication when I use MAP110, and I was able to write the first command to it (/?!\r\n). So I recieved the appropiate response from the device (a text with info about the device):

/LGZ5\2ZMG405000b.P07
☻1-0:0.0.0(1296885)
!
♥<

When I write to get this response, the Landis has a little telephone icon which means that it's communicating

The next step is to send what I think is called "ACK", and here's the problem, because I try to read it and always get nothing. Also, the telephone icon doesn't show.
From what I know, the configuration of the device at this point changes. The baudrate changes from 300 to 9600. I think the parity changes from Even to None. The stopbits keep at 1. I think that the bytesize changes from 7 to 8 but maybe not. I don't know if I have to change it before or after writting the prompt. I also don't know if I have to close and open the port to change the configurationsm but I think not.
But I have already tested all this possibilities mixed so I don't think it's a problem from this.
According to the monitoring of MAP110, the chain I have to write as this ACK is 06 b2 35 b2 8d 0a, and I would have to be able to read the same thing, because the device responds with the same chain.

In 06 b2 35 b2 8d 0a, 06 is the ACK, b2 is the character ², 35 is 5 which refers to the baudrate and 8d 0a is CR LF

I searched in internet about the protocol and i found a pdf which in this part of the communication says:

---->
ACK
060

So i also tried with 30 36 30 8d 0a (which is 060 + \r and \n in hexa) but it also didn't work.

I've already tried mixing everything every possibility: I tried to put the configuration in between the write and the read, to put it before the read, I tried with 300bps with 9600bps, with bytesize 8, bytesize 7, with stopbits 1 and 2, with parity None, Even and even Odd and Space. Of course none of this attempts were succesful.

So I feel like it's a problem with the chain I'm sending, it may not being readed because it has to be a different chain

I also tried to change the 35 in the ACK to every 1 digit number (from 30 to 39)